# How to set RxJs (BehaviourSubject) next() method as null with Strict type enabled?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular11

I'm learning rxJs and Angular 11, looking at an example I came across this snippet of code, refer to the `logout` method towards the end.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { User } from '@app/_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public user: Observable<User>;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
        this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get userValue(): User {
        return this.userSubject.value;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('user');

        //I'm getting error -> Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.ts(2345)
        this.userSubject.next(null);  


        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I rather not disable strict type, and I messed around with '?' but no luck. If I understand correctly, passing null is simply to clear data previously there?

**UPDATE 1**

So I changed `private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;` to `private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;` Not sure if this is even proper/correct but app runs...

**UPDATE 2**
As stated by comment from Pankaj Sati, using `null as any` works as well!

Comment: Try `private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User | null>`

Comment: Or you can try `this.userSubject.next(null as any);`

Comment: Ahh that's nice way to do it! `null as any` worked, but `User | null` didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work, using a `union` type

```
private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User | null>;
```

You may need to add in some null checks when accessing the `user` value in `subscribe` functions, but you're probably doing this already